# Why would a professor not reply?

Tags: professorship, research-undergraduate, email, supervision, projects

A professor has offered me a summer research project at his lab. The last we had talked was on a Zoom call during which I was offered the position. He had then asked me to send my academic records after which he would give the other documents like Offer Letter, Visa Forms, etc. I have mailed him my records and have asked to discuss the project dates. He is not responding to my emails. It's been almost 20 days. I have also sent follow-ups, the last one being sent this Monday. He still hasn't responded.

Has he cancelled my project? If so, why hasn't he informed? What should I do next? Should I send another follow up this Monday?

Comment: Many universities are still on break.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the 20 or so days covers holiday periods there might be a simple answer. The professor might be traveling. Might even be sick, given the pandemic. You can follow up if you like, but keep it polite. If you have access to the department email address, you could ask them if there is a reason that they might not be replying.

Don't jump to conclusions, but follow up with other options that you have.

Comment: (+1) Normally 20 days (to me) is getting past a reasonable waiting period (but still within some people's response times . . .), but the two things you've pointed out -- holidays and pandemic -- make things quite a bit less unreasonable. Moreover, the existence of these two possibilities affecting things also provides a good excuse-opening for an email request to the department itself.